# Yahoo Pure Heading Error Alignment

Tags: html, css

The Yahoo Pure.io code below works as expected in Chrome, IE.  But not in Firefox. Menu suppose to be like this,

Heading Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4

but in Firefox,

Heading

```
               Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4
```

Below is the code.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
        <a class="pure-menu-heading" href=""">Heading</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Menu2</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Menu3</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zx3nL8jo/)

Comment: It looks the same in both. Can you point out using a screenshot?

Comment: can't copy the screenshots, but it's that the Heading is above the Menus, suppose to be horizontal menu. I'm using Yahoo's Pure.